# RoR App error deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a very basic RoR app and deployed to heroku.

after going to website given by heroku I see this message:

"Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

I have tried **heroku restart**

The error logs I get back are:

> 2018-03-10T04:04:08.519299+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=agile-chamber-72076.herokuapp.com request_id=4dda4e3d-450f-43e3-91a7-cf19d4f9b108 fwd="71.58.221.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2018-03-10T04:04:08.917146+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=agile-chamber-72076.herokuapp.com request_id=3845e226-5c2c-43e8-a2ee-0c0b4bae66e7 fwd="71.58.221.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2018-03-10T04:04:34.531282+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=agile-chamber-72076.herokuapp.com request_id=9c25fcbd-1939-48ec-8603-5b2424c2182e fwd="71.58.221.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2018-03-10T04:04:34.822620+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=agile-chamber-72076.herokuapp.com request_id=c4a93941-8d85-4631-b4a2-51d627403022 fwd="71.58.221.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: Did you get any errors while deploying?

Comment: No, everything seemed fine until this.

Comment: Did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: I just tried it and its still not working. I did change the dyno to 1 as per the advice of another post.

Comment: Can you run it locally, I've gotten this error when I forget to close a method with `end`

Comment: Yes, it works fine locally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be troubleshooting Heroku error [`H10 - App crashed`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed), the app crashed for many causes if you run `rails c` on your Heroku dashboard or from your computer `heroku run rails c` then it gives more specific errors like something wrong with `ActiveRecord` query and line number is like `13` and file is `../app/models/` or something like this, I'm writing some reference why sometimes app crashed to the Heroku.

**Some possible causes**

- ActiveRecord associations are not properly handled.
- The gem that Heroku requires (pg 0.20 or 0.11.0)
- vendor/cache
- Some code got broken when refactoring.
- The database schema is not updated.
- Ruby version changed

Or something other