# My Rails app is deployed but not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have my Rails app deployed, but when I go to open it, I get this error in my web browser :

> Application error
>   An error occurred in the application and your page could not beserved. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Here are my log errors:

> 2018-03-19T04:48:12.360662+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=marmelade1.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=613511e2-940f-4aac-8f42-7fa7f85a8a76 fwd="172.90.196.64"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2018-03-19T04:48:31.712091+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=marmelade1.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=813d50a1-8cee-4a57-81d5-b9f303084cf6 fwd="172.90.196.64"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2018-03-19T04:48:32.039194+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=marmelade1.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=854ceb16-62c4-430e-9771-d64bb334f006 fwd="172.90.196.64"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2018-03-19T05:01:26.721459+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=marmelade1.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=e112728e-af23-48c1-aef2-c2fd995466dd fwd="172.90.196.64"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run migrations in your Heroku environment?

Comment: That is very difficult to say where is the problem, without troubleshooting code the `code=H10` error described on Heroku dev center as well https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed, I have tried to explain some key points about that error on the other same question which is yours see this, I think might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/49219418/4172515

Comment: Here's a different answer to a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24113266/49 -- it's been upvoted a lot of times so I think it might be helpful. Best of luck!

Comment: in console write: heroku run rails console, it will show you a better error explication

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error. Rails 6.1.4.1 ruby 2.7.1p83
I ran `$ heroku run rails console`

Below was the error at the bottom of the terminal: Error loading the 'postgresql' Active Record adapter. **Missing a gem it depends on? can't activate pg (~> 1.1), already activated pg-0.18.4.** Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (LoadError)

I updated the postgresql gem version from 0.18.1 to 1.1 in my gem file, pushed the changes to heroku and the issued was fixed.